# UITableView adds a margin of white space to my cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am utilizing a custom cell that has an imageview but for some reason the tableview is adding a thing margin of white space to the right of the cells and I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is how it looks like: [image]

This is a screenshot from the simulator (the teal stuff is the navigation bar, the image is content from a user) and to the right of the image you can see a gray/white margin

The Cell has an Imageview and  two UILabels and a smaller imageview within the main Imageview.Here is the xib:

[image]

Here is how it is being implemented:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MSTableViewCell *cell = (MSTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"MSTableView2" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id obj in nibArray){
            if([obj isMemberOfClass:[MSTableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (MSTableViewCell *)obj;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, cell.bounds.size.width, 0.f,0.f);

    UIColor *listColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"767676"];



            cell.itemName.text = @"hey";
            cell.userName.text = @"sup";

    //[cell setItemImage:[object objectForKey:@"image"]];
    cell.itemImage.file = [object objectForKey:@"image"];
    [cell.itemImage loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

    }];
return cell;
}
```

There are no insets as you can see.

Comment: You are going to need to provide a lot more details about how the cell is setup and how the image view is setup.

Comment: @rmaddy i added more details